# Prove $x^y>y^x$ by using convexity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

For $y>x>e$, show that $x^y>y^x$.

It is not hard to prove this inequality by using the monotonicity of $\frac{\ln t}{t}$. I am curious if this inequality can be proved by using convexity of functions. If so, which function should we consider?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

$$x^y > y^x \iff \sqrt[x]{x} > \sqrt[y]{y}$$

which is true because the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}$ is strictly decreasing from $e$ to $\infty$, i.e it's convex

Comment: I think strictly speaking this is still a monotonicity proof

Answer (score 0):

set $y=kx$ for $k \gt 1$, so you wish to show that if $x \gt e$ then
$$
x^{kx} \gt (kx)^x
$$
i.e.  $x \gt e$ implies
$$x^{k-1} \gt k
$$
so it is sufficient to show that for $k \gt 1$ we have
$$
k \ge 1 + ln \; k
$$
so can you find a convexity proof for this?